# fnmatch during walk() keeps producing erroneous file locations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why fnmatch() doesn't work in this loop. Every time I run it, it says that's a file with the argument I passed is in every directory I traverse. I can't figure out why. I've gone as far as re-writing my entire app, only to be met with the same behavior. Anybody have any idea why this would be happening?

```
import os
import argparse
import fnmatch

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""This application takes a string and navigates the file system looking
                                         for either a file or directory with the name of the string that was
                                         passed. The output should be the absolute path (e.g. full path) to the
                                         directory or file.""")
parser.add_argument('Root',
                type = str,
                help = 'This is the root directory to start looking in. This is required.',
                )
parser.add_argument('String',
                type=str,
                help = 'This is the string to use to search for file or directory. This is required.',
                )
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                help = 'This will force the program to only list files. This is optional.',
                action = 'store_true',
                )
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory',
                help = 'This will force the program to only list directories. This is optional.',
                action = 'store_true',
                )
parser.add_argument('-m', '--last-modified',
                help='The time the file/directory was last modified. This is optional.',
                action = 'store_true')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = parser.parse_args(['/Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python', 'testfile'])

else:
    arguments = parser.parse_args()

root_directory = arguments.Root
search_string = arguments.String

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    for dir in dirs:
        for file in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, search_string + ".*"):
                print "File found at: " + os.path.join(root, dir, file)
```

A file matching "testfile" is located in only 3 of the following folders, yet for every folder that exists, an erroneous filename is printed.

```
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/.idea/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Argument Passing/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Assignment 1/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Assignment 2/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Assignment 3/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Assignment 4/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/ClassExample/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/dummy/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/file.system/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Hangman/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/HierarchyDemo/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/InheritanceExample/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/prob2/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Quiz 4/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Rosalind/testfile.txt
File found at: /Users/marco/Dropbox/School/Python/Quiz 4/testfile/testfile.txt
```

Comment: You aren't using `os.walk` right. `dirs` is a list of folders located in `root`, and similarly, `files` is a list of files located in `root`. You're however outputting each file in root once for each folder in root.

Comment: @Rawing thanks! I was going crazy trying to figure that out. The lecture notes provided by my professor show a similar implementation above with 2 nested loops in the main loop. I'll have to talk to him about that.